# Reports on view creation in clearcase

Tags: report, clearcase

I'm in the process of creating report on static of

View creation for a particular month
total number of views
View deletion.

Any insight would of great help.

Lot of reports planned, second one is this. First one is license usage.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point for that report would be to use [`cleartool lsview -age`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm) (for view access and usage).

But the creation date a a view is only visible in the properties a view (`cleartool lsview -l -full -pro`), which means you would need to launch a global `lsview` on a regular basis, and parse the output of those properties for each view, in order for you to detect:

- newly created view
- recently deleted view

That detection would be done again the previous list of views as recorded by the previous launch of your `lsview -pro`.